# Dev Ops housekeeping unused variables and debugging variable 'VSTS_PUBLIC_VARIABLES' exceeds the maximum supported length

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking for help for below 2 Dev Ops related topics
1) I am frequently getting warning on my Log "Environment variable 'VSTS_PUBLIC_VARIABLES' exceeds the maximum supported length"
I wanted to see which line of code/configuration/ parameters length is exceeding overall. is there any way to pin point code/ parameter etc to fix

2)I have heaps of variables under variable groups under different projects and many variables seems not in use being part of poor process. I want to trace each variable incase linked with a pipeline. or any other way to cleaning up unwanted variables

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

About the first question: This is windows environment limitation. We can’t deal with it in Azure DevOps. You could try to use shorter folder name and fewer levels. You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/936836/environment-variable-vsts-public-variables-exceeds.html) about this .

About the second question: As far as I know, there is currently no out-of-the-box feature to achieve it. We should only exclude unused variables by searching one by one or use scripts to retrieve variables that match the variable names in the variable group.

The variable group works on multiple pipelines, and the variables may not be used in the current pipeline, but may be used in other pipelines. At present, there should be no such function to check which variables are used in the corresponding pipeline.